# Robot Framework Remote Server

Tags: selenium, robotframework

In the company here i would like to run Robot Framework tests on every computer without installing Robot Framework.

Can i install Robot framework on a server and every client can send a robot test file to a webserver and they run the test. For now i have tried the [Selenium Hub](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp). This works perfect but i will make Robot Framework make remote too. Is this possible to do it? Can i do it with the remote libaries ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My solution would be:

1. A Linux server with SSH, where every user would login and run the tests.
2. A Jenkins server with proper Plugins to run each modified test.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try docker create containers one manager and others as nodes this would help , Only in main container you need to have robot framework and supporting libraries the other containers can inherit from master

Answer (score 0):

You can use Robot framework without installing it.
You have to use gradle for that. You can define Robot framework as dependency for your gradle project.
So when project will build, gradle framework will satisfy all the dependencies and you can run your robot code without installing anything.

I have developed complex  testing application with robot framework and gradle. I didn't install a single application for my robot test cases to run.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve exactly that easily with [Robocorp Cloud](https://robocorp.com/robocorp-cloud) and their API.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Robot Framework Coding offer the remote library from the robot suite file in the *** Settings *** section with Library option.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Remote    http://127.0.0.1:8270       WITH NAME    Example1
Library    Remote    http://example.com:8080/    WITH NAME    Example2
Library    Remote    http://10.0.0.2/example    1 minute    WITH NAME    Example3
```

In this way of resources management we need to put the libs in one machine.
Make sure the machine is accessible over same network or public IP.

However I feel that running suite in a container environment is better solution.
We can prepare a Docker image of all the dependencies and then store the image at repository of image any open source and internal, for example dockerhub.

https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#remote-library-interface